# Turn off hot reloading on webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created a reactjs app with webpack. Everything works fine on local. Just by using npm start. I want to deploy a simple package for prod with webpack -p command. it gave me a bundle.js I appended it, and it works fine too. but it is still looking for my local server running as part of hot reloading config. I changed hot:false, but its still looking for it.

here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://csd.local.com:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')})

  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    {  test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

And here is my server.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: false,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://csd.local.com:3000/');
});
```

All I want is, turn off hot reloading in prod.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're telling webpack to bundle HMRE's client-side scripts together with your app:

```
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://csd.local.com:3000',
'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',**strong text**
```

The solution would be to detect wether you're in "development" or "production" environment. To do so you can use "yargs" to parse your cli arguments (it's a webpack dependency so you don't even have to install it), and use the result to dynamically build your config.

```
var production = require('yargs').argv.p;
```

See a complete example at http://pastie.org/10895795

Comment: You link is down.